# Disk not found error when trying to create a VM from a saved disk

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine

I am getting a disk not found error when trying to create a VM from a saved disk.

I can go on the azure portal and see the disk, so it is there.

here is relevant code:

```
$vmConfig = New-AzVMConfig -VMName $vmName -VMSize "Standard_A2"
$vm = Add-AzVMNetworkInterface -VM $vmConfig -Id $nic.Id

$vm = Set-AzVMOSDisk -VM $vm -ManagedDiskId $disk.Id -StorageAccountType Standard_LRS `
    -DiskSizeInGB 128 -CreateOption Attach -Windows

New-AzVM -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -Location $LocationName -VM $vm #FAILS HERE
```

Here is the error:

```
New-AzVM : Disk python3disk20210616a is not found.
ErrorCode: NotFound
ErrorMessage: Disk python3disk20210616a is not found.
ErrorTarget: /subscriptions/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/resourceGroups/rg-comphydro/providers/Microsoft.Compute/disks/python3disk20210616a 
StatusCode: 404
ReasonPhrase: Not Found
OperationID : 3fe239be-5af4-4231-aaec-b77e9cd77fb7
At line:1 char:1
+ New-AzVM -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -Location $LocationNam ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [New-AzVM], ComputeCloudException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Compute.NewAzureVMCommand
```

if I print $disk, this is what is displayed:

```
ResourceGroupName            : rg-comphydro
ManagedBy                    :
ManagedByExtended            : {}
Sku                          : Microsoft.Azure.Management.Compute.Models.DiskSku
Zones                        :
TimeCreated                  : 6/16/2021 4:20:06 PM
OsType                       : Windows
HyperVGeneration             : V1
CreationData                 : Microsoft.Azure.Management.Compute.Models.CreationData
DiskSizeGB                   : 128
DiskSizeBytes                : 137438953472
UniqueId                     : 085da610-953d-4f9c-8303-ad4b2b7e7e50
EncryptionSettingsCollection :
ProvisioningState            : Succeeded
DiskIOPSReadWrite            : 500
DiskMBpsReadWrite            : 60
DiskIOPSReadOnly             :
DiskMBpsReadOnly             :
DiskState                    : Unattached
Encryption                   : Microsoft.Azure.Management.Compute.Models.Encryption
MaxShares                    :
ShareInfo                    : {}
Id                           : /subscriptions/XXXXXXX/resourceGroups/rg-comphydro/providers/Microsoft.Compute/disks/py 
                               thon3disk20210616a
Name                         : python3disk20210616a
Type                         : Microsoft.Compute/disks
Location                     : northcentralus
Tags                         : {}
NetworkAccessPolicy          : AllowAll
DiskAccessId                 :
Tier                         :
BurstingEnabled              :
```

Answer (score 0):

I have successfully created the virtual machine from PowerShell by using the below list of commands

```html
$resourceGroupName = "resourcegroupName"
$location = "westus"
$vmName = "name of the VM"
$disk= Get-AzDisk -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -DiskName "diskname"
$nic= Get-AzNetworkInterface -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -Name "Networkinterfacename"
$vmConfig = New-AzVMConfig -VMName $vmName -VMSize "Standard_D2s_v3"
$vm = Add-AzVMNetworkInterface -VM $vmConfig -Id $nic.Id
$vm = Set-AzVMOSDisk -VM $vm -ManagedDiskId $disk.Id -StorageAccountType Standard_LRS -DiskSizeInGB 128 -CreateOption Attach -Windows
New-AzVM -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -Location $location -VM $vm
```

Comment: @Ryan Conway, if the above provided answer was helpful ? If so could please mark accept the answer as a solution. This could help other community users who have similar query in the future.